# SQL Server 2008 query check date on same day

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've written a query to check whether more than one record exists on the same day. Currently the excerpt from my query that performs the restriction looks like this :

```
GROUP BY 
    entry_date 
HAVING
    COUNT(entry_date) > 1
```

As the entry date column is defined as a `datetime`, does it check against the full datetime or just the date?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know SQL Server, but what do you get if you select that column?

Comment: '2015-06-25 09:31:25.807' Would be if you did a select statement on that column.

Comment: Then you have to extract the date part from it, both in group by and having clauses. (Or, even better, have a derived table where you do that part.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `entry_date` is `DATETIME` ,your group by wont work as expected.you need to `CAST` it to `DATE`.[Cast(Datetime)to date is sargable](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/526431/make-more-functions-sargable) as well.

```
GROUP BY cast(entry_date as DATE)
having count(cast(entry_date as DATE)) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't `cast` or `convert` it to anything else, naturally it uses all data available. So it would group data together with the exact same datetime. Why would you expect anything else?

Comment: Hi, I only asked as when I perform that statement and view the records I get data such as '2015-07-15 19:30:05.970' - '2015-07-15 19:30:05.547' returned. Which suggests it might not respect the millisecond value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It should be full datetime.

```
CONVERT(date, entry_date)
```

should separate out the date.